# Не работает модальное окно с версией Jquery?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Всем привет с версией Jquery-1.4.3.min.js модальное окно работает нормально. Но мне на сайте нужна более новая версия jquery-1.10.1.min.js. Подключаю ее и вуаля ничего не работает. Выдает ошибку в коде.

```
$('a[data-reveal-id]').live('click', function(e) {
undefined is not a function
```

Что можно сделать?

Comment: А что вам именно не нравится? Или чего вы не понимаете? Ошибка по делу, показа где она, надо просто исправить, в чем же тогда затруднение?

Comment: я исправил

Comment: вот видите.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сразу же нашел решение. Убрали метод live. Теперь используем On.